# Temporal variable is updated

Tags: python

I am sure it might be a small mistake that I didn't see:

I am creating two arrays. R and Qvalues. The initial values of Qvalues are stored in R and Qvalues is updated in using multiple for loops. However, for some reason, R is also updated. But R is not mentioned anywhere else. I'd like you help, thanks. Code below:

```
import numpy as np 
import random      
import time

gamma = 0.8
Rewards = np.array([[-1,-1,-1,-1, 0, -1], 
                  [-1,-1,-1,0,-1,100],
                  [-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1],
                  [-1,0,0,-1,0,-1],
                  [0,-1,-1,0,-1,100],
                  [-1,0,-1,-1,0,100]])

Qvalues = np.zeros((6,6))

maxim= np.amax(Rewards); 
indices = np.argwhere(Rewards == maxim)
Qvalues[indices[:,0],indices[:,1]] = maxim

change  = 1
indices = np.argwhere(Qvalues == maxim)

R = Qvalues
print(R)

for i in range(len(indices)):
    c_index = indices[i,0]  
    zeros_ind = np.argwhere(Rewards[:,c_index] ==0) 
    for l in range(len(zeros_ind)):
        if(Qvalues[zeros_ind[l],c_index]==0):
            Qvalues[zeros_ind[l],c_index] = gamma*maxim
print(R)
```

Comment: `R = Qvalues` does not make a *copy* of the object.

Comment: As @deceze said, you are referencing using pointers. Check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. One thing still bugs me: when I do similar examples, I do not have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, `R = Qvalues` does not make a copy of the object.

Try `R = Qvalues.copy()` or `.deepcopy()`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html